# jQuery Alert for MySQL Integrity Contraint Violation (Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5

I haven't been able to locate an answer specifically for my case, so I'm hoping I can at least find suggestions here.

On my Laravel application, I have a MySQL table with a secondary key using the combination of two fields in said table. If a duplicate tries to be inserted, I get the following returned `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '...key...' for key 'pro_number_origin` and the return code is `500`.

However, I am curious if there are any suggestions for how to return a jQuery alert (at the very basic level) specifically for cases where MySQL spits back the return saying that there is already an entry with specific parameters. Or maybe even a different way around this, I'd prefer not to add additional requests if I don't have to and just use that specific return.

Answer (score 0):

When using AJAX, Laravel returns a JSON response of the stack trace, you can look through the stack trace and try and locate specific unique words which will differentiate errors and base your alerts on that.

A simple example would be:

```
if (response.toLowerCase().includes('duplicate entry')) {
    alert('A duplicate entry key error was thrown.');
}
```

Now, that can be expanded further to include different error types.

**or**, a more complicated way would be the create custom exception handlers for your AJAX based errors and provide clean outputs for each error type in a JSON key that could be labelled as `error`.